# How can I search emails from a specific month in gmail

Tags: gmail

How can I search emails from a specific month in gmail.I use gmail in chrome or microsoft edge mostly on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en&ref_topic=3394593)

> Search for messages sent during a certain time period
>
> ```
> after:2004/04/16
> before:04/18/2004
> older:2004/04/16
> newer:04/18/2004
> ```

Date can be specified as `YYYY/mm/dd` or `dd/mm/YYYY`.

---

So use something like `after:2019/01/01 before:2019/02/01`.